# How To Insert a Common Point Between 2 Pen Lines

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6

I need to insert a common point in between 2 pen lines so I can draw a shape by overlapping lines and deleting lines after the point.

thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. To be honest, it would better to do work like this with Illustrator.  Photoshop has only very basic vector capabilities, so it's not really the right kind of software. This kind of thing is so easy in Illustrator using the Shape Builder tool. [See example here](https://imgur.com/a/wuJCwUF)

Comment: @BillyKerr I understand. what I don't understand is why a powerful tool like Photoshop doesn't allow me to do such thing.

Comment: It's not designed for this kind of work. Photoshop is a raster image editor first and foremost, with very limited vector functionality.  Illustrator is totally different - it's a specialist vector image editor with much more functionality for manipulating vectors. The two are different tools for different jobs.  It's like how you can use a hammer to fix a screw with brute force, but a screw driver is a much better tool for the job.

Comment: ok thank you guys. I'll, try Illustrator.

Answer (score 0):

Click with the **Add Anchor Point Tool**.

There's no automated solution for this. Photoshop is, at best, **rudimentary** when it comes to vector path and shape editing.

Comment: yeah but I won't be able to add an anchor point right in the intersection. I also need to do this in many lines (over 50).

Comment: I will try to use Illustrator.

Comment: Illustrator won't automatically add anchors at intersections of multiple paths either.

Comment: thank you Scott. but is it possible to do that with Illustrator?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.. in addition all anchor points in Ai or PS can only connect **2** path segments. So at an intersection of multiple paths the *best* you could do is add an anchor to **each** path, then overlap those anchors.